# How to report problems in the Edge browser to Microsoft?

Tags: microsoft-edge

Our big, single-page JavaScript app does not work at all in the Edge browser. (We officially support it in Chrome and Firefox, we don't allow it to be used in IE because it only half works there, and we chose not to do all the IE specific work.)

I have submitted issues in the past to the webkit team via their bugzilla tracker.

I have googled around and do not see a way to submit issues to the Edge team at all.

Is there a known way to collaborate with Microsoft on Edge?

Comment: Please elaborate more on what "does not work at all" means. Do you get specific errors in the console? Do certain animations/transitions not work? Are you able to post a code snippet that seems to cause the problem?

Comment: I rolled back to remove what seems to be an answer to support So's Q&A posts' format

Answer (score 17):

The following channels are great ways to interact with the Microsoft Edge team:

- Bug reports: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/
- Feature requests: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer
- Demos, documentations, and projects: https://github.com/microsoftedge
- Social: https://twitter.com/MSEdgeDev

Comment: Great list. All of these are linked to from our main portal at http://dev.modern.ie

Comment: Good luck with that! I tried to report an issue but you have to sign in to do so. I don't have any account with Microsoft, and there is no visible link in the issue tracker page to create one.

Comment: @ejosafat - That's good feedback and I'll let the Edge team know. In the meantime, you can create a Microsoft account at https://account.microsoft.com/.

Comment: Thanks! I'll register as soon as I get an example outside my app reproducing the issue.

Comment: This answer is outdated as most of the links don't work. Are there new links?

Answer (score 5):

You can click the "Send Feedback" option, which appears when you click the ellipsis ("...") on the right of the browser window, right below the "X" close button.

Answer (score 4):

In the new Edge browser, open the ellipsis menu at the top right of the browser window and click **Help and feedback** and **Send feedback**.

[image]

Alternatively press Alt+Shift+I to directly open the feedback window.

Answer (score 0):

You need to report them to the Feedback portal entry for Microsoft Edge at https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/post/b8da43d5-ef1b-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472. Relevantly, bugs for Edge can be viewed at https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/b8da43d5-ef1b-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472.