# Microsoft Edge not firing HTML5 audio metadata

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, microsoft-edge

Seemingly, none of the following HTML5 Media events are fired in the Edge browser, under Windows 10:

- loadeddata
- loadedmetadata
- canplay
- canplaythrough
- timeupdate

At least that's based on the following [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amigolargo/m9ofjz88/), running on a virtualbox VM:

```
audioEl = document.createElement('audio');
audioEl.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.maninblack.org/demos/WhereDoAllTheJunkiesComeFrom.mp3');
audioEl.play();

audioEl.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
  console.log('loadedmetadata');
});

audioEl.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
  console.log('loadeddata');
});

audioEl.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
  console.log('canplay');
});

audioEl.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() {
  console.log('canplaythrough');
});

audioEl.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
  console.log('timeupdate');
  console.log(audioEl.readyState);
});
```

Is there something I'm missing here, before I [report this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31799142/how-to-report-problems-in-the-edge-browser-to-microsoft) to Microsoft?

Comment: Can't repro Edge 25.10586 on a windows10 VM too

Comment: Thanks for checking. Seems I'm a few versions behind (20.10240.16384.0). Windows says it is up to date however, did you upgrade Edge through the OS, or another way?

Comment: Installed this VM last week, from MS site himself, no update yet.

Comment: Interesting. I have the latest build from the MS site for Virtualbox: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/mac/, at the risk of being off-topic, what VM software are you using, and where did you download the VM? thanks!

Comment: Ah, I use VirtualBox on a mac, and just downloaded and installed the [iso of Win10 from MS](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) :  I selected the normal one 64bits if I do remember correctly (iso file name is Win10_1511_English_x64.iso)

Comment: @amigolargo When you navigate to *Windows Update* from the Start menu, you are not presented with any updates?

Comment: @Sampson, nope, sadly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, the Virtualbox VM downloaded from modern.ie was not reporting any available updates, nor allowing me to update, which meant that Edge was stuck at v20.10240.16384.0. These features mustn't have been implemented in that build. Downloading the [windows ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO)  as per @kaaido's comment, and installing that manually, gave me access to the most recent build of Edge, and the events are now firing as expected.